# Retrieve the keys based on the specific values when using list to store the values of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my dictionary:

```py
 my_dict = {"james": (0,"computer vision", "open cv", "image processing","python",'machine learning'), "jhon": (0,"computer vision", "open cv", "image processing","python",'machine learning'),"Rajeev" : ("python","machine learning","nltk","nlp",1), "bapi": ( 0,"python","machine learning","nltk","nlp") }
```

I want to retrieve key if the values match this below pattern so the output should be `bapi`. I have tried the below code and the output can be seen below.

```py
my_color = [0,"python","machine learning","nltk","nlp"]
[k  for k, v in my_dict.items() for j in my_color  if j and 0 in v]
#This is the output
['james',
 'james',
 'james',
 'james',
 'jhon',
 'jhon',
 'jhon',
 'jhon',
 'bapi',
 'bapi',
 'bapi',
 'bapi']
```

Comment: `if j and 0 in v` is not doing what you think it's doing, it's evaluated as `if j and (0 in v)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
[x for x,y in my_dict.items() if y==tuple(my_color)]
```

Output:

```
['bapi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually compare whole tuples without looping through the elements:

```
print([k for k, v in my_dict.items()  if v == tuple(my_color) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

[x for x,y in my_dict.items() if y==list(my_color)]

Answer (score 0):

```
In [7]: my_dict = {"james": (0,"computer vision", "open cv", "image processing","python",'machine learnin
       ...: g'), "jhon": (0,"computer vision", "open cv", "image processing","python",'machine learning'),"Ra
       ...: jeev" : ("python","machine learning","nltk","nlp",1), "bapi": ( 0,"python","machine learning","nl
       ...: tk","nlp") }

    In [8]: my_color = [0,"python","machine learning","nltk","nlp"]

    In [9]: [ key for key, val in my_dict.items() if all( j in val for j in my_color ) ]
    Out[9]: ['bapi']

    In [10]:
```

Edit:

"all" takes a list in which all values has to be true for it return true

```
for e.g. --> all( [True, True] ) will return True
where as --> all([True, False]) = will return False
```

so inside all when i'm doing
--> if all( j in val for j in my_color )

basically I'm checking if every value in my_color exist in  value of dictionary_item.

```
--> all( j in val for j in my_color ) 
will be equal to 

--> all( (0 in val) , ('python' in val), ('machine learning' in val) ,('nltk' in val) , ('nlp' in val) )
```

if all of the values are true then all will return true

Comment: Can u please break down your solution, i am new to python and i dint understand what "all" is doing,sorry and thank you in advance..@Kunal Sawant

Comment: added an edit . nothing to be sorry about . welcome.